# can we be able to pass webrequest object into servicebus queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

can we be able to pass webrequest object into servicebus queue?

```
var WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://test.com/test");
            var connectionString = "xxx";
            var queueName = "xxx";

            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            try
            {
                var message = new BrokeredMessage(WebRequest.GetRequestStream());

                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("error found");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> var message = new BrokeredMessage(WebRequest.GetRequestStream());
>
> client.Send(message);

As far as I know, `WebRequest.GetRequestStream()` returns a ConnectStream and it is a write-only stream.

[image]

If you call [QueueClient.Send method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.send?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_) to send message with the stream that you passed as BodyStream to Service Bus Queue, the SDK would read and serialize the BodyStream, but the stream returned by GetRequestStream method does not support reading.

Normally, we don't do anything with the request stream but writing to it, could you explain the actual goal of saving the request stream in queue message?

Comment: I am creating generic component which should push web request into azure queue.I need to do that without any loss of information like missing post data e.g  data may be XML,json etc.

Comment: I am creating this for processing long running request on the back end long running process like report generation.If request hits the server(back end) , I will respond with success after queuing the request in Azure queue.

Comment: ``I need to do that without any loss of information like missing post data e.g data may be XML,json `` If possible, you could upload/store these XML (or json) files to Azure blob storage, and send message with request url &request method etc &the url of XML(or json) file that stored in Blob. And then back end could make request based on queue message.